# Update property's value in datagrid based on another property's input

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpfdatagrid

I have an observable collection binded to a datagrid. On a datagrid row, when I edit a property's value I need another property on that row to update it's value based on a calculation. What is the best way to go about doing this. I tried creating a collectionchanged method like below:

```
   Public WithEvents Tickets As ObservableCollection(Of Ticket)

Public Sub Tickets_CollectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) Handles TicketCollection.CollectionChanged
    CalculatedVariable = determineCalculation()
End Sub
```

However this it only called when a new item is added or deleted, not when a property within the row is edited. Another way I looked at is calling the calculation method within the setter of each property but that seems messy knowing that i would need to call that method and update the property on several different properties that I need it on. Is there a good easy efficient way that I can accomplish what I'm trying to do? Thannks for any feedback :)

```
 public property MyVariable
 Get 
     return _MyVariable
 Set(value)
     _MyVariable = value
     CalculatedVariable = determineCalculation()
     RaisePropertyChange("MyVariable") , ect..
 EndProperty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class of the elements listed by your ObservableCollection has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. You have to raise the PropertyChanged event in your setters. Then you can subscribe to this event inside your class and make the calculation in the callback. I find it a little bit cleaner than doing the calculation in each setter, and anyways you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged if you want the UI to be updated when you change any property of your object.

Comment: I do call the RaisePropertyChanged in my setter that does implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Thats what is weird cuase it still doesn't get called. I updated anwser to show getter setter example

Comment: Actually what I have above with the getter and setter but without the calculatedvariable is what i have. That property is within the model class that inherits a class that has my raisepropertychanged. Am i missing something in the setter or do I somehow have to call something else?

Comment: Another solution might be to use multibinding with a converter in which you do the calculation...

Comment: yea I'm not a fan of converters :(

Comment: I also think it's a little bit messy to call determineCalculation() directly in each setters, I suggest you do the call in the callback of the PropertyChanged event. Are you just trying to find a better solution, or is your *messy* solution not working ?

Comment: Well like you said, using the collectionchanged event is my first choice, but if worst comes to worst i'll just have to do everything in the setters of my properties which works, I just think its dirty

Comment: I'm not speaking about the collectionchanged event - as you said it's a missuse since it is only called when elements are added or suppressed from your collection. I'm thinking about subscribing to the PropertyChanged event of your class (in its constructor), and then in the callback of this event, do the call to determineCalculation() - NOT in each setters of your properties. In the setters of your properties you should only have _myVariable = value and the raising of the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: ah I see what your talking about. I would have to create a special INotifyPropertyChanged Methods for this model then. Right now I have one class that implements INotify.. with my raisepropertychange and from there all my models inherit that class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15348/discussion-between-franssu-and-tman)